# Not able to apply Scan in place of For loop

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I have been advised to avoid procedural loops and use other functions like  **Scan,NestList, FoldList, NestWhileList, Inner and Outer**. My worry is that if I have a need in which certain critical parameters have to be calculated at the end of each loop and then passed on to the next iteration which in simpler terms would mean that *certain outputs of an iteration have to be passed as inputs for the very next iteration*, then how to go about that.

ForEg:

```
list1 = Scan[someFunction,someList]
```

Suppose `someFunction` has certain input parameters `a; b;` with some initial values at the beginning which are to be used for the first iteration only.
Let `c; d; e;` be the output where `e` is the main output to be stored in `list1` while `c` and `d` are to be passed as input to `a` and `b` respectively in the very next iteration.

Actual Example:

```
a=1;b=1; (*For first iteration only*)

someFunction[inp_] :=

(
 e=inp+a+b;
  c=e^2;
   d=e^3;
 e
);

someList=Range[0,0.1,0.0001];

list1=Scan[someFunction,someList];
```

Comment: What is `someList`?  I think you are looking for either `FoldList` or `NestList` but I cannot tell from your description which one.  Possibly also `Fold` or `Nest` combined with `Sow` and `Reap`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I meant an arbitrary function called `someFunction` is applied to an arbitrary list called`someList`

Comment: It would help me if you included an actual `For` loop you wish to refactor.  My confusion comes from the fact that you say `someFunction` has the "input variables" (usually called parameters if I understand) `a` and `b`, and these are filled from the output `c` and `d` of the previous iteration.  This sounds like `Nest` or `NestList`.  However if `someFunction` has additional parameters that should be filled from `someList` then I think you want `Fold` or `FoldList`.

Comment: You'd better give a concrete example.

Comment: Scan applies a function to each element of a list BUT does not return anything (well it returns Null); it is intended to be used on functions that operate through side effects.  If you're expecting a list of results from applying a function to a list of inputs then you want Map not Scan.

Comment: in your "Actual Example" `a,b` never change.  Your question implies you have a working `For` loop solution, you should actually show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific example, why not:

```
FoldList[# + #2^2 + #2^3 &, 1, someList]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what is the role of `someList` in what you're trying to implement, but if I understand you correctly you can do it with `Table`:

```
c=a; d=b;    
Table[{c,d,e}=someFunction[c,d,x];e , {x,someList}]
```

Comment: Where exactly `c=a;` and `d=b` would have to be added in the code, within the function `someFunction` or outside.